# Run through a column and if #N/A is present, replace with cell directly to right of it (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to develop a macro in Excel that runs through a column and if the value states #N/A, it replaces it with the cell directly to the right of the respective cell. So if the column that am I searching for the #N/As is Column H, the values that I would pull from would be the next column over in Column I. Below is the code I am trying to build:

```
Dim NACol As Range
Dim NARange As Range

Set NARange = DEV.Sheets("Input File Creator (DND)").Range("H2:H100")

Set NACol = .cells.Find(What:="#N/A", _
        after:=.Range("H2"), _
        lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        searchorder:=xlByRows, _
        searchdirection:=xlPrevious, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row

For Each NACol In NARange
     'Paste the cell directly from the cell to the right
Next
```

I am stuck on the For 
Each if that is the correct way approach this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Something like this `NACol.Value = NACol.Offset(0, 1).Value`?

Comment: Could you use, ISNA in the formula, so if(isna(x1),y1,x1) something like that.  What errors/issues do you have?

Comment: Can you change the initial formula that create the #N/A error? If so, maybe use the IfError() formula to select the cell you want when it errors out.

Comment: If I follow your logic, you should iterate over that returned range of Find / FindNext. But I'd do another way, iterating over the complete NARange and checking for NA against every cell.

Comment: are the N/A constants or formulae ?

Comment: @Ralph let me give your suggestion a shot

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I never actually heard of the ISNA formula before, I will give that a shot as well

Comment: @RyanWildry I cannot change the formula in the cell as those link from different sheets so any altering my affect the desired output

Comment: @PA. I hope I am understanding your logic as it sounds good so do you mean first gather all the N/As first then move forward with changing it?

Comment: @iDevlop the N/As are a result of a formula so they are not constants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the shortest and fastest way, since it loops only the **errors** cells in the given range.  If your error values are constants instead of formulae, juste change `xlCellTypeFormulas` into `xlCellTypeConstants`.

```
Dim c As Range, NARange  as range
Set NARange = DEV.Sheets("Input File Creator (DND)").Range("H2:H100")

For Each c In NARange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
    If Application.IsNA(c) Then c.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next c
```

Comment: this looks promising and simple, let me give this a shot!

Comment: is there a way to delete the cell and the respective cell to the LEFT if even after we run it and it pulls another #N/A from the right? @iDevlop

Answer (score 0):

How about something nice and simple. Highlight the column with N/A error and click run.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Selection

    For Each c In rng

        Debug.Print c.Value

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(c.Value) Then c.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value

    Next c


End Sub
```

Comment: I would use something like the following for range ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlFormulas, xlErrors)

Comment: Would you use that instead of Set rng = Selection?

Comment: Yes, as iDevelops answer in fact :)

Answer (score 0):

Your implimentation is a bit off for both the loop and your search conditions.  Assuming the #N/A value is the result of a formula error, this code should clear that up.

```
Dim NARange As Range, CheckCell As Range

Set NARange = DEV.Sheets("Input File Creator (DND)").Range("H2:H100")

For Each CheckCell In NARange
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(CheckCell) Then
         CheckCell.Offset(0,1).Copy
         CheckCell.Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste  'Doing this rather than value will bring formatting
    End If
Next CheckCell
```

Comment: thank you for looking at my process and noticing where I was off.